# Get value from textbox based on checkbox on change event

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have two textboxes and one checkbox in a form.
I need to create a function javascript function for copy the first txtbox value to second textbox on checkbox change event.

I use the following code but its shows null on first time checkbox true.

```
function ShiptoBill()
{
  var billing = document.getElementById("txtbilling").value;
  var shipping = document.getElementById("txtshipping").value;
  var check = // here i got checkbox checked or not
  if(check == true)
  {
    // here I need to add the txtbilling value to txtshipping
  }

}
```

Comment: Strictly using Javascript, or are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: @tempranova he tagged jquery..go give jquery answer..OP should provide more info

Comment: @tempranova Javascript

Comment: @User then remove tag jquery

Comment: Problem is the textbox1 value is didnt saved at first time while check the checkbox so its shows null

Comment: Are you attaching this function to the onclick event of the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Given that form controls can be accessed as named properties of the form, you can get a reference to the form from the checkbox, then conditionally set the value of *txtshipping* to the value of *txtbilling* depending on whether it's checked or not, e.g.:

```html
<form>
  <input name="txtbilling" value="foo"><br>
  <input name="txtshipping" readonly><br>
  <input name="sameas" type="checkbox" onclick="
   this.form.txtshipping.value = this.checked? this.form.txtbilling.value : '';
  "><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Of course you might want to set the listener dynamically, the above just provides a hint. You could also conditionally copy the contents over if the user changes them and the checkbox is checked, so a change event listener on *txtbilling* may be required too.

Answer (score 0):

Try like following.

```js
function ShiptoBill() {
  var billing = document.getElementById("txtbilling");
  var shipping = document.getElementById("txtshipping");

  var check = document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked; 

  if (check == true) {
    shipping.value = billing.value;
  } else {
    shipping.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbilling" />
<input type="text" id="txtshipping" />
<input type="checkbox" onchange="ShiptoBill()" id="checkboxId" />
```

```
function ShiptoBill()
{
    var billing = document.getElementById("txtbilling");
    var shipping = document.getElementById("txtshipping");

    var check = document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked; // replace 'checkboxId' with your checkbox 'id'

    if (check == true)
    {
        shipping.value = billing.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not a problem.I already got the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I've updated my answer. @User

Answer (score 0):

To get the event when it changes, do

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change',function() {
  if($(this).checked) {
   $('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
  }
});
```

This checks for the checkbox to have a change, then checks if it is checked. If it is, it places the value of Input Box 1 into the value of Input Box 2.

**EDIT: Here's a pure JS solution, [and a JSBin too](https://jsbin.com/qibava/edit?html,js,console,output).**

```
function ShiptoBill()
{
  var billing = document.getElementById("txtbilling").value;
  var shipping = document.getElementById("txtshipping").value;
  var check = document.getElementById("thischeck").checked;
  console.log(check);
  if(check == true)
  {
    console.log('checked');
    document.getElementById("txtshipping").value = billing;
  } else {
    console.log('not checked');
  }
}
```

with

```
<input id="thischeck" type="checkbox" onclick="ShiptoBill()">
```

Comment: Ah. Just removed jQuery. haha. OK... sec.